# How "Artificial Intelligence" abbreviation should be written?

Tags: discussion

Is it AI or A.I., or both abbreviations are fine? Basically, with the dots or without?

Answer (score 4):

In British English it has to be "AI". 
In American English it can be both "AI" and "A.I.".

Sources:

- http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/words/punctuation-in-abbreviations-american
- Oxford A–Z of Grammar and Punctuation by John Seely.
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_stop#Abbreviations_and_personal_titles_of_address

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, I've never seen it written "A.I.", but both look fine to me. If somebody wants to use the dots, more power to them. As Marqin showed, it's kind of dependent on whether a person is using British or American English. Suggested edits that only change stylistic things like this should be rejected; let the post author choose as long as it's consistent within a post.

If there is ever a similar question about tag names, the official policy is that the American style should be used. (SE is an American company.)

Source: [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23873/295684)